# Cross-Platform webcam access

Tags: cross-platform, directshow, quicktime, video-capture, video4linux

I'm looking for a cross-platform video capture library, for webcam access. One that wraps V4L/V4L2 on Linux, DirectShow on Windows, and QuickTime on the Mac.

C or C++ is preferred, but I can work in Java or Python if those have better options for libraries.

Answer (score 9):

The [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome) (Open Source Computer Vision) works under Linux, Windows and Mac OS X.

I use OpenCV under Mac OS X and it works very well with the built-in iSight of my MacBook, and I believe it works equally well under the other platforms.

Of course, OpenCV is not primarily intended as video capture library, but it can be used as such. And if you want to process the frames you grab from your webcam OpenCV will definitely help you with that...

Answer (score 6):

[Openframeworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/) has a video grabbing component which is meant to be cross platform, perhaps you could just use the framework for that piece :)

Answer (score 1):

Two other projects that let you access Webcams from Java:

1. [LTI-Civil](http://lti-civil.org/)
2. [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler)

Answer (score 0):

**JMF** (Java Media Framework) has libraries in Linux/Windows too, and has some support for webcam capture.

**Formats**

http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/formats.html