# How do I retrieve picture snapshots from a web cam?

Tags: c++, webcam

How difficult is it to make software for a webcam such as the Gateway USB 2.0 Web Cam?  I would like to be able to retrieve picture snapshots on demand.  Is there a C++ library or other API that I may use to do so?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688165/cross-platform-webcam-access

Comment: Duplicate?.. o xD lol look at that lol. sorry i did not see that post.

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on what platform you are using.  For example, if on Windows, you can retrieve data from the camera using the [DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375454%28VS.85%29.aspx) API, Linux has [Video4Linux](http://linux.bytesex.org/v4l2/) and Mac has [QuickTime](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/).

There are some cross-platform wrappers which provide a layer above the native video API, and therefore offer a common API across multiple platforms.  One such project is [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome) which - although not intended primarily for camera capture use cases - does support them via the `cvCaptureFromCAM` and `cvQueryFrame` functions.

The [QtMobility](http://labs.trolltech.com/page/Projects/QtMobility) Multimedia APIs will also offer cross-platform camera support, but this API is not yet implemented.  Check back in Qt 4.7 if this library looks interesting to you.